# Non-exhaustive patterns in Haskell function

Tags: list, haskell

I have a problem with a haskell program. I want to do something like this:

```
main = do
    print $ map foo [(1, [(2, 3), (4,5)])]

foo :: (Int, [(Int, Int)]) -> (Int, [(Int, Int)])
foo (a, [(b, c)]) = (a+1, [(b, c)])
```

Then i get the run-time error:

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function Main.foo
```

How is it possible to make such a action?
I just want to access the parameters which are not in the list.

Comment: See also `first` from `Control.Arrow`: `foo = first (+1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(a, [(b, c)])` does not match `(1, [(2, 3), (4, 5)])`, because the list in the latter has two elements while your pattern requires there to be only one.

If you want to leave the list unchanged, use this pattern instead:

```
foo (a, bar) = (a+1, bar)
```

Now `bar` will match `[(2, 3), (4, 5)]` because it is just a binding which will match anything of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, it is a warning, telling you that there are some cases in which none of your patterns in `foo` will apply. If no pattern is matched, the programme will quit with an error, therefore it gives you this warning.

You may choose to ignore this warning if you're 100% sure that this pattern is always matched. Your match in `foo` will fail if the second part of the pair contains `!= 1` list elements. I am quite sure you meant to do something like this:

```
foo (a, l) = (a+1, l)
```

To copy the given list.

Comment: "Non-exhaustive patterns" is a runtime error.  It occurs when you pass a function an argument and none of the function's patterns match the argument.  There is also a compile-time warning that warns this might happen, but that's not what he's referring to.